# Git - How to push a commit to master such that it shows up in history after a certain commit

Tags: git

I had to make some fixes to a previous commit (tagged as v4.3_1.0.10).

Listed below are the steps I performed:

1. git checkout tags/v4.3_1.0.10 (message says that it is in detached HEAD state)
2. git checkout -b v4.3_1.0.10-fixes v4.3_1.0.10
3. Made changes to the code in this new branch.

My questions are:

1. How do I push this commit to master such that it shows up in history after the v4.3_1.0.10 commit? I believe I have to do an interactive rebase, but not sure if that is the right thing to do.
2. Will this push over-write any of the commits done after v4.3_1.0.10?

I searched, but did not find anything similar to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do an interactive rebase and put a commit in the middle of the history, all later commits will appear different.

If you try to push you will receive a message that there is a push conflict (the push is `non-fast-forward`).

That push conflict can be resolved by a force push `git push -f`. However if you are on a repository that is being used by other people as well that might have checked out the old branch when they try to push the will not be able to do it (for the same reason as you).

So to be clear, there is no good way to alter the previous history of a public project.

What you could do is create a new tag on your new branch and push that to your remote, and then apply the commit on top of master as well.

Comment: So, what you are saying is something like this? git tag <tag name>; git checkout master; git push --tags; git merge <old branch name>; git push

Comment: almost, I think that `git merge <old branch name> will not be a good idea, I suggest to `cherry-pick` the commit to master

Comment: So the cherry-pick will basically apply the old commit on top of master? But what will happen if someone pulls from this commit and not the latest commit?

Comment: well, I get it that this commit is essential and needed for all versions and all versions should get it. The old version will do that from the new tag and the new will get a new commit on its top (if needed). so the master users will just pull and receive the patched version